# "attribute nam"e can not be resolved as member of "object"

Tags: java, jsf

i got this issue a class containing protected attributes :

Test Class:

```
abstract public class Test extends WithAttachment{
static ISQLTest pISQLTest = null;

// Ajour une refence au campagne ??? pour resoudre le Warning

/**
 * Date de creation du test
 */
protected Date creationDate;

/**
 * Nom complet du concepteur du test
 */
protected String conceptorName;

/**
 * Login du concepteur du test
 */
protected String conceptorLogin;
.....}
```

Managed bean :

```
    private Test selectedTest; // with getters and setters
```

xhtml page :

```
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="4" header="Test Details">

                                  <h:outputText value="Name of The Test :" />  
                                  <h:outputText value="#{projectTestManagementMB.selectedTest.name}" /> 

                                  <h:outputText value="Creation Date :" />  
                                  <h:outputText value="#{projectTestManagementMB.selectedTest.creationDate}" /> 

                                  <h:outputText value="Executed :" />  
                                  <h:outputText value="#{projectTestManagementMB.testExecutedFlag}" /> 

                                  <h:outputText value="Owner :" /> 
                                  <h:outputText value="#{projectTestManagementMB.selectedTest.conceptorName} #{projectTestManagementMB.selectedTestconceptorLogin}" /> 


  </h:panelGrid>
```

so when i try to access them in my xhtml page in EL expression i get this error ;
t
`attribute name can no be resolved as member of selectedTest`

So is there a possibility to solve this problem without changing the access type (protected) of class Test attributes .

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @AmitaGL.. Please convert your comments and error messages into `English` before posting.. We can't understand what you have written there.. Although it is not required for this purpose.. But remember for future reference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just as it says - there's no "name" attribute in `Test`, unless that's in `WithAttachment` which you haven't shown us.

You've got `conceptorName`, but not `name`. Admittedly I don't know whether having a protected field will be good enough anyway - I'd *expect* a private field and a public `getName()` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
#{projectTestManagementMB.selectedTest.name}
```

Where is your attribute `name`?? in `Test` class..

Comment: @AmitaGL.. What?? Can't understand??